# UIView does not appear after alpha property gets reset to 1.0

Tags: ios, uiview, alpha

I've got this test code where you tap a `UIView` (currently a small square) which causes it to fade out from that current coordinate, then reappear at another randomized coordinate (repeating this sequence forever, currently).

My problem is the square is not reappearing at the new location (whose coordinates are part of an observable region in the superview (the background).

Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [self fadeMenuOut];
    [self spawnDot];
    [self setUpSpawnTimer];
}

- (void)fadeMenuOut {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:(void (^)(void)) ^{
                     self.dot.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     self.dot.hidden = YES;
                     self.dot.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                 }];
    [self.dot removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"fadeMenuOut");
}

- (void)spawnDot {
    int newX = frandom_range(40.0, 220.0);
    int newY = frandom_range(40.0, 220.0);
    NSLog(@"dot:%@", self.dot);
    CGRect frame = self.dot.frame;
    frame.origin.x = newX;
    frame.origin.y = newY;
    self.dot.frame = frame;
    self.dot.alpha = 1.0;
    self.dot.hidden = NO;
    self.dot.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   [self.view addSubview:self.dot];
    NSLog(@"dot:%@", self.dot);
    NSLog(@"spawnDot");
}

// took this from another SO member
static inline CGFloat frandom() {
    return (CGFloat)random()/UINT32_C(0x7FFFFFFF);
}

static inline CGFloat frandom_range(CGFloat low, CGFloat high) {
    return (high-low)*frandom()+low;
}

- (void)setUpSpawnTimer {
    [self.spawnTimer invalidate];
    NSTimer *newTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(fadeTheDot)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
    self.spawnTimer = newTimer;
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:newTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    NSLog(@"setUpSpawnTimer");
}

// if, after 5 seconds, the button isn't tapped, it disappears and you lose
- (void)fadeTheDot {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:(void (^)(void)) ^{
                     self.dot.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     self.dot.hidden = YES;
                     self.dot.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                 }];
    [self.dot removeFromSuperview];
    [self.spawnTimer invalidate];
    NSLog(@"fadeTheDot");
}
```

Here's the output:

```
2017-04-22 12:18:32.341 DotFever[916:570634] fadeMenuOut
2017-04-22 12:18:32.343 DotFever[916:570634] dot:<UIView: 0x17d3b9d0; frame = (130 254; 60 60); alpha = 0; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17d3b2d0>; animations = { opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0x17e40850>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x17d3bb70>>
2017-04-22 12:18:32.345 DotFever[916:570634] dot:<UIView: 0x17d3b9d0; frame = (191 110; 60 60); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17d3b2d0>; animations = { opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0x17e40850>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x17d3bb70>>
2017-04-22 12:18:32.345 DotFever[916:570634] spawnDot
2017-04-22 12:18:32.346 DotFever[916:570634] setUpSpawnTimer
2017-04-22 12:18:34.347 DotFever[916:570634] fadeTheDot
```

Notice how, when the second `NSLog` of my `UIView` object `self.dot` gets called, the `self.dot.alpha` property doesn't appear (even though, which you don't see here, I've logged `self.dot.alpha` at that point in which it says 1.0).

Is there something I'm doing wrong with handling my view?  It's created in `Main.storyboard`.  Originally, at the start, the view is completely centered on the screen via the storyboard constraints for an Any/Any scenario.  Thanks.

/// UPDATE

```
- (void)spawnDot {
    UIView* newDot = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((int)frandom_range(40.0, 220.0),
                                                          (int)frandom_range(40.0, 220.0), 60, 60)];
    NSLog(@"self.dot:%@", self.dot);
    [self.view addSubview:newDot];
    self.dot = newDot;
    self.dot.alpha = 1.0;
    self.dot.hidden = NO;
    self.dot.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    NSLog(@"dot:%@", newDot);
    NSLog(@"self.dot:%@", self.dot);
    NSLog(@"spawnDot");
}
```

with output:

```
2017-04-22 14:19:19.727 DotFever[1033:590311] self.dot:<UIView: 0x155ac070; frame = (130 254; 60 60); alpha = 0; hidden = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x15697990>; layer = <CALayer: 0x155ac210>>
2017-04-22 14:19:19.729 DotFever[1033:590311] dot:<UIView: 0x15684d60; frame = (191 110; 60 60); layer = <CALayer: 0x15684280>>
2017-04-22 14:19:19.730 DotFever[1033:590311] self.dot:<UIView: 0x15684d60; frame = (191 110; 60 60); layer = <CALayer: 0x15684280>>
2017-04-22 14:19:19.730 DotFever[1033:590311] spawnDot
2017-04-22 14:19:19.731 DotFever[1033:590311] setUpSpawnTimer
```

Comment: Add an `NSLog` statement inside both the `animations` and `completion` blocks in your `fadeMenuOut` method and you will see the problem.

Comment: Weird, so the `animation` block runs on some background thread (is what I'm thinking)?  Because my `NSLog` statement in the `completion` block executes after the `setupSpawnTimer` `NSLog` statement executes.  How do I fix this, or does the animation run time dictate without flexibility?

Comment: Should I create an execution delay for the follow-up methods (`[self spawnDot]`, `[self setupSpawnTimer`])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is being caused mainly by the fact that the completion block in `fadeOutMenu` is being called after the call to `spawnDot`.

Also note that your call to `[self.dot removeFromSuperview];` at the end of `fadeMenuOut` needs to be moved to the end of the completion block. As it is now, you won't see any animation. But this is a side issue.

To solve your overall issue, I would add a completion block parameter to your `fadeMenuOut` method. Call this completion block at the end of the UIView animation block's completion handler.

The block you pass to this completion parameter should call your `spawnDot` and `setUpSpawnTimer` methods.

On a side note, I would also update your `fadeTheDot` method to call `[self.dot removeFromSuperview];` at the end of the `UIView animation's completion block. Again, this will fix the lack of an actual animation.

Comment: Oh that's much better, makes the "delay" for the follow-up methods arbitrary (or, rather, they rely on the 1 second fade out of the menu....or 3 seconds, 4, etc.).   Thanks rmaddy.  And the `[self.dot removeFromSuperview]` inside the `completion` block makes something apparent actually happen, thanks.

Comment: Just as a follow-up, I've never gotten my hands dirty with storyboards or xibs too much, so if I call `[self.dot removeFromSuperview]` on that `UIView` object created through storyboard, how do I reassign a new instance to it given that it's a weak property?  I can't make this new view appear for some reason.

Comment: I would use a local variable to reference the new view as it is created. Assign the local variable to the weak property after you add the new view as a subview.

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck.  I posted an update above with the new `[self spawnDot]` code.

Comment: You know what gets to me sometimes....my inability to seek the simplest source of confusion.  Turns out, (given that I was working with a white background for `self.view`) the `newDot` instance was a white color...so it was blending in with the background the entire time.